# Compute electric field intensity (EFI)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

An infinite long hollow semicylinder of radius R has a uniform surface charge density P(s)

a.What is the electric field intensity (EFI) along the axis of that semicylinder ?

b.Use the result from (a) to find EFI along the axis due to semicylinder of uniform volume charge P(v) ?

---

I don't understand this problem 
Please help me !!!

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize the Gauss law to find the field along the axis of full cylinder.

Then use symmetry arguments to conclude that the field due to semicylinder is half that due to whole cylinder.

For Part 2,

U can either use Gauss law again, or integrate field due to individual hollow cylinders that comprise the solid cylinder.